# Merge two maps into one

Tags: kotlin

I have to maps. One is `Map<String, Double>`, like "USA, 55.87". Second is `Map<String, String>`, like "USA, United States of America".

And I want to turn this maps into `Map<Result, Double>`. Where `Result` contains two String, like "USA, United States of America". How to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data class Result(
  val abbreviation: String,
  val name: String
)

fun main() {
  val firstMap = mapOf("USA" to 12.34, "CAN" to 56.78, "MEX" to 90.12)
  val secondMap = mapOf("USA" to "United States of America", "MEX" to "Mexico", "GON" to "Gondor")

  val result = firstMap.keys.intersect(secondMap.keys).associate { Result(it, secondMap[it]!!) to firstMap[it] }

  println(result)
}
```

`firstMap.keys.intersect(secondMap.keys)` will give you the set of keys in common between your two maps, in case there are keys that are only in one map and not the other. `associate()` builds a `Map`, where you are passed a collection member (in this case, a map key) and you return a `Pair` representing an entry in the resulting `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

If you have strong reason to believe that the keys in both maps will always match, you can do the following:

```
data class Country(
    val abbreviation: String,
    val name: String
)

fun main() {
    val firstMap = mapOf("USA" to 12.34)
    val secondMap = mapOf("USA" to "United States of America")

    print(firstMap.mapKeys { Country(it.key, secondMap[it.key] ?: error("Country ${it.key} not found in second map")) })
}
```